# Trisurf cannot plot into specified axis

Tags: matlab, axis, handle, surface, triangular

I would like to make a triangular surface plot throught the function `trisurf`, targeting a specified axis. However, MATLAB documentation does not indicate any syntax to do that. When I open the function I get the following first lines:

```
function hh = trisurf(tri,varargin)
%TRISURF Triangular surface plot
%   TRISURF(TRI,X,Y,Z,C) displays the triangles defined in the M-by-3
%   face matrix TRI as a surface.  A row of TRI contains indexes into
%   the X,Y, and Z vertex vectors to define a single triangular face.
%   The color is defined by the vector C.
%
%   TRISURF(TRI,X,Y,Z) uses C = Z, so color is proportional to surface
%   height.
%
%   TRISURF(TR) displays the triangles in the triangulation TR. It uses
%   C = TR.X(:,3) to color the surface proportional to height.
%
%   H = TRISURF(...) returns a patch handle.
%
%   TRISURF(...,'param','value','param','value'...) allows additional
%   patch param/value pairs to be used when creating the patch object. 
%
%   Example:
%
%   [x,y] = meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
%   tri = delaunay(x,y);
%   z = peaks(15);
%   trisurf(tri,x,y,z)
%
%   % Alternatively
%   tr = triangulation(tri, x(:), y(:), z(:));
%   trisurf(tr)
%
%   See also PATCH, TRIMESH, DELAUNAY, triangulation, delaunayTriangulation.
%   Copyright 1984-2017 The MathWorks, Inc.
narginchk(1,inf);
ax = axescheck(varargin{:});
ax = newplot(ax);
start = 1;
```

The function input is not defined just as `varargin`, as it is done in function `surf` for example, so it is not possible to specify the axis handle as first input variable. If the axis handle is specified as second input variable, the function `axescheck` recognize the handle, but later I get an error because the expected second input variable is a vector. If the axis handle is specified as third input variable the function `axescheck` does not recognize the handle at all.

I know that I can first activate the axis and then call `trisurf`, but I have this inside a loop so it is not advisable to do that. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the axes handle of the one you are interested in, what you can do is make the current axis that one by`axes(youraxeshandle)`, and the just use `trisurf` without any specific input. It should be added to the current axis, which is the one you selected.

Comment: Yep, this is what I meant with first activating the axis and then calling `trisurf`. However this is not efficient in a loop. With other plotting functions in fact it is possible to target an axis without making it current axis. I was wondering if there is a solution to do this with `trisurf` as well.

Comment: @Francesco I think this is your only option, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Since this is still unanswered:

`trisurf` creates a `Patch` object, which like most graphical objects, has a `Parent` property.

```
% ax1 is the handle of you first axis
trisurf(k, x, y, z, 'Parent', ax1)
```